# How to add senders name while sending a mail using WebMail

Tags: email, razor

My current code is:
`WebMail.SmtpServer = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";

WebMail.From = "support@shayonainfo.com";`
While I send a mail using above code the senders name at the receivers side is shown as "support" instead of that I want to show "Shayona".. I tried doing something like I did in C#.net but not 
`WebMail.From = new MailAddress("support@shayonainfo.com", "Shayona Infocom");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WebMail.From = "Shayona Infocom support@shayonainfo.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answer by @Tom Studee
I tried it and found that on the receiver's side the senders name is shown as `<Shayona Infocom>`.. I tried editing the answer by him but unfortunately it didn't worked..

So **finally this worked for me:**
WebMail.From = "Shayona Infocom support@shayonainfo.com";